# Python regular expression for extracting html tags beginning with a number

Tags: python, regex

i have a text file which is somewhat of this manner ,

```
<b-colophon>
data
</b-colophon>

<1|1|1|>
data,data,data
</1|1|1>


<1|1|2>
data,data,data
</1|1|2>
```

So , i wanted to make the tag as key and data within the tag as the value and so came with the code -

```
dict1 = {}
lines = file.readlines()
for i in range(len(lines)):
        try:
            if lines[i].startswith('<') and lines[i + 1] != '\n':
                dict1[lines[i].strip()] = lines[i + 1].strip()
        except:
            print("File read complete!")

print(dict1)
```

But i require only the tags starting with a '<' and next containing a number to be added to the key and the string enclosed within that tag to be added to respective value. But the above code adds all the tags starting with a '<'. I want to be able to add only tags beginning with '<' followed by a num to be added as key , not even </> (closing tags) only the opening tags. Please help.

Comment: Why have you tagged this `regex` yet you are not using regular expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all:

```
<1|1|1|>
data,data,data
</1|1|1>
```

Should be:

```
<1|1|1|>
data,data,data
</1|1|1|>
```

The method that comes to mind for this is to use regular expressions:

```
<(\d+[^>]*)>\s*([\s\S]*?)\s*</\1>
```

1. `<` Matches <
2. `(\d+[^>]*)` Matches one or more digits followed by 0 or more none > characters in capture group 1 (the tag)
3. `>` Matches >
4. `\s*` Matches 0 or more whitespace characters
5. `([\s\S]*?)` Matches 0 or more characters non-greedily in capture group 2 (the data)
6. `\s*` Matches 0 or more whitespace characters
7. `</` Matches </
8. `\1` Matches capture group1 (the tag)
9. `>` Matches >

The above regex removes leading and trailing whitespace from the data (items 4. and 6. above).

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AqfrkE/3/)

The code:

```
import re

text = """<b-colophon>
data
</b-colophon>

<1|1|1|>
data,data,data
</1|1|1|>


<1|1|2>
data,data,data
</1|1|2>
"""

rex = r'<(\d+[^>]*)>\s*([\s\S]*?)\s*</\1>'
dict1 = {m[1]: m[2] for m in re.finditer(rex, text)}
print(dict1)
```

Prints:

```
{'1|1|1|': 'data,data,data', '1|1|2': 'data,data,data'}
```

Naturally, you would modify the above code so that `text` is `file.read()`, that is, the entire contents of the file as a single string.

If you want the `<` and `>` as part of the dictionary keys, then make the following change:

```
rex = r'<(\d+[^>]*)>\s*([\s\S]*?)\s*</\1>'
d = {'<' + m[1] + '>': m[2] for m in re.finditer(rex, text)}
print(d)
```

Prints:

```
{'<1|1|1|>': 'data,data,data', '<1|1|2>': 'data,data,data'}
```